# Motor vector control and parameters estimation

Tags: motor, control, induction-motor, electric-machine, vector-control

Vector control methods require good estimation of magnetic flux. In Direct Torque Control it would vector of stator flux. In order to estimate it properly one has to know motor parameters such as rotor and stator resistances and inductances and mutual inductance as well.

Best would be to perform free and locked rotor tests and obtain those parameters accurately by experiment, however it is not always easy to do (for example when motor is already connected to the load machine and you can't easily dismount it). There are some other methods, like calculating the parameters from nameplate data (nominal power, nominal speed, current, slip, Istart/Inom and so on). However this method has quite a big margin of error, up to -/+ 50%.

Thing is the motor and control scheme would still work, even with such high mismatch of parameters. Most likely not as good as with perfect parameters, transients would be longer and with higher oscillations but it would eventually still work. And since in real world you don't have information about real stator flux, how can you know how bad the parameters are under or overestimated?

[image: Stator flux estimated (red) and real directly from model (blue)]

Please take a look at above picture. In simulation I can easily know that parameters are in mismatch as estimated stator flux (red, calculated from nameplate data of modeled motor) doesn't correspond to real stator flux (blue, modeled motor paremeters). How can I know it in real world, with physical motor and an actual inverter?